# Inserting a column value in between row value

Tags: mysql

In my database I have 1000+ rows of data that I need to modify a bit. The *content* column. I've given it try and the closest i've come was using [RPAD](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_rpad.asp)

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET content = RPAD("mySlides/", LENGTH(username)+9, username);
```

Using RPAD remove all the text after though, so I believe RPAD isn't the way to go about this.

I'm trying to insert the *username* column after the "mySlides/" text but also not to remove the following text after. Just place right in between.

Is this possible?

**Here is an example I mocked up.**
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Not sure how RPAD is supposed to help here. The length of the beginning part _before_ the position where you want to insert the username appears to be the same here in each instance, so you `SUBSTR` to extract the rest after that position, and then CONCAT it together with the static prefix and the username.

Comment: Use common REPLACE().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using the `CONCAT` function.

Here an exemple :

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME_C
SET content = CONCAT('<img src="../myslides/', username, '/', SUBSTRING(content, INSTR(content, '/')+1));
```

Explanation

`INSTR()` is used to finds the position of the first occurrence of '/'. `SUBSTRING()` extracts the substring of the content column starting from the position after the first occurrence of the character '/' till the end of the string.

db fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fpoiGLnEzFQAmFRkkibEWn/1

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET content = REPLACE( content, 
                       'mySlides/', 
                       CONCAT( 'mySlides/', 
                               username, 
                               '/'
                              )
                       )
```

Comment: Awesome. This would work too. Thank you!